# make count in percentage by using counter_cache rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**I need to make votes_count in percentage**.

My relations are

celebrity.rb

```
has_many :votes
```

vote.rb

```
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
```

My controller

```
def show_celebrity
  @celebrity = Celebrity.includes(:category).where('category_id = ?', params[:id])
  @celebrity.each do |celeb|
    celeb["votes_count"] = celeb.votes.count
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @celebrity }
  end
end
```

how can I make the votes_count in percentage? votes / total no. of votes *100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like you already wrote:

```
@celebrity = Celebrity.includes(:category).where('category_id = ?', params[:id])
total_votes = Vote.count.to_f

@celebrity.each do |celeb|
  celeb["votes_count"] = (celeb.votes_count / total_votes * 100).round(2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In `celebrity.rb` you write method `percentage_of_votes` it will return `percentage` value, call from `controller`

```
class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your code goes here....
   def total_votes
     Vote.count
   end

   def percentage_of_votes
     (self.votes_count.to_f / self.total_votes.to_f * 100.0).round(2)
   end
end
```

In `controller` call method `percentage_of_votes`

```
    def show_celebrity
      @celebrity = Celebrity.includes(:category).where('category_id = ?', params[:id])
      @celebrity.each do |celeb|
        celeb["votes_count"] = celeb.percentage_of_votes
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @celebrity }
      end
    end
```